# How to connect localhost phpmyadmin to android emulator

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm having trouble in the HttpPost part because it cannot create a connection. I tried in the browser by entering in the address bar `ipaddress/directory` or `127.0.01/directory`. It works but in the android part it doesn't.

Comment: did get connection refused

Answer (score 0):

to work with emulator change `127.0.0.1` to `10.0.2.2` refer [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) 
and make sure you have set the Internet permission in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

You should check out this : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias

(use the alias "10.0.2.2" instead of "localhost" or "127.0.0.1")