# Connection is refused

Tags: android

I am trying to insert data through Android app using PH + MySQL and I am using phpMyAdmin but every time connection is refused.

My IP is `127.0.0.1`.
My directory inside the localServer (like WAMP,XAMPP) `android_connect`.
Inside the Android connect I have a PHP file named `create_product.php`.

```
    <?php

    /*
     * Following code will create a new product row
     * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
     */

    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();

    // check for required fields
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];

        // include db connect class
        require_once('db_connect.php');

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
  ?>
```

My `127.0.0.1` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.domore.operationsjson.NewProductActivity">

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input Name -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <!-- Price Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input Price -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

    <!-- Description Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input description -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:lines="4"
        android:gravity="top"/>

    <!-- Button Create Product -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnCreateProduct"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Product"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my Android javafile name is `android_connect`

```
package com.domore.operationsjson;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;
    String name,price,description;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        name = inputName.getText().toString();
        price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

For connection I am also using `create_product.php` with port,
but it's not working. Error is `add_product.xml`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you check this ?[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837315/how-to-connect-localhost-phpmyadmin-to-android-emulator)

Comment: are you running it on emulator?
If yes then use IP 10.0.2.2

Comment: I tried everyting but i got same error everytime

Comment: The address you are trying to connect to, is the localhost, the device itself.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 0):

http://myipaddress.com returns your external IP iddress not the IP of your localhost. If you are using MAC or Linux use `ifconfig` in terminal, In case of windows use 'ipconfig' in command prompt. The ip address will usually be in 192.x.x.x or something like that.

Make sure your laptop and the android mobile are in the same network. And also do check you have declared internet permission in manifest

Answer (score 0):

I am using a local php server so i need to set my IP like this

```
http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php"
```

it' Work perfectly to solve my error.